# Haskell: What is "!" in this definition of a Datatype using data

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, record

#### Background

I came across this syntax [here](https://github.com/OlivierNicole/haskell-chess/blob/master/ChessBoard.hs). (lines 43-44 and 65-71)
I will adapt this to a minimally reproducible example like so:

```hs
data Bar = X | Y
data Baz = A | B

data Foo = Foo !Bar !Baz
```

Here is an implementation for `Show`, if you desire one.

```hs
instance Show Bar where
  show X = "x"
  show Y = "y"

instance Show Baz where
  show A = "a"
  show B = "b"

instance Show Foo where
  show (Foo X t) = map C.toUpper $ show t
  show (Foo Y t) = show t
```

### Problem

Notice the definition of `Foo`. The sigil `!` precedes its fields `Bar` and `Baz`. I do not understand what this signifies and am unable to find related documentation either. What does that mean?

Comment: Ah, this is just strict evaluation then?

Comment: Yes. `Foo e1 e2` will always evaluate `e1` and `e2` before constructing the value. Those constructor fields marked with `!` are strict. By default, all fields are lazy instead.